# File organizer based on extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, file-system

I'm still new to programming and I'm not confident about this code. I recently created this File Organizer that organizes files in folders based on their extensions. How can I make this code cleaner?

````
# File Organizer - organizes file in folders based on their extensions.
# 03/05/2020

import shutil, os

root_path = "C:\\YourDesiredPath" 
os.chdir(root_path) 
dirfiles = os.listdir(root_path) 

class FileOrganizer():

    # store extensions and folder names
    mydir = {}

    def name_folder(self):
        for file in dirfiles: 
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            if ext != '': # if file has an extension
                self.mydir[ext] = (ext + " FOLDER").upper()

    def create_folder(self):
        for folder in list(self.mydir.values()): 
            if not os.path.isdir(folder): 
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))

    def organize_files(self):
        for file in dirfiles:
            # for files iterated, check if it matches the ext and move it to ext folder
            for ext in [*self.mydir]:
                if file.endswith(ext):
                    try:
                        shutil.move(file,self.mydir[ext])
                    except :
                        print(f"{file} already exists in {self.mydir[ext]}")


file_organizer = FileOrganizer() 
file_organizer.name_folder()
file_organizer.create_folder()
file_organizer.organize_files()
```
````

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241644/file-automation-using-python-on-linux) from the same day. It seems to be similar to what you are doing, albeit not the same. The answers contain general tips that apply to your problem as well.